# How to self-study a sufficient real-analysis course

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning, book-recommendation

I'm currently a high school freshman trying to find some resources for studying higher math. I've read through some Intro to Proof books, Stewart's Calculus (and other supplementary calculus materials), linear alg by W. Curtis, and diff eq by Simmons.

I read through the first two chapters and did the problems in the first chapter of Basic Real Analysis by [Knapp](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eaknapp/download/b2-realanal-inside.pdf), and I realized I probably am not ready for that level of difficulty. The propositions build off each other rapidly, the most specific examples plug in something intensely general like the real numbers for a set, and there are barely any diagrams. So, I self-studied using [Trench's](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF) RA, which has been a lot more fruitful and the problems are at least natural. I've seen a lot of other questions asking for books on Intro to RA, though I really would like to have the ability to go through something like Knapp's book or even the sequel (Advanced RA) because it seems very interesting. I also have a friend who may be interested in reading it in the future.

Are there any supplementary materials that could help with this or should I be looking for something else? I am particularly confused because I don't know the target demographic for Knapp's Basic RA.

(I hope this falls under understanding concepts in the community guidelines cause idk where else to ask it)

Comment: Yes: Abbott's book is what you want! Googling yields a [PDF](https://homel.vsb.cz/~ulc0011/Abbott%20-%20Understanding%20Analysis.pdf).

Comment: This mostly seems like an introduction to Chapter 1 of Basic RA, which I mostly understood. Thanks for the resource, but I don't think this is what I'm looking for. Essentially I just want something that gives a good intro to something like Lebesgue measure theory, advanced metric spaces, etc.

Comment: If you are looking for a book whose focus much on measures you can go with the classic Rudin book. If you are familiar with multivariable calculus should be good.

Comment: I would recommend Spivak’s *Calculus*. If you know all the “standard” material thoroughly, concentrate on all the analysis and proof exercises. You should not attempt measure theory and abstract metric spaces before you’ve mastered the basic real analysis.

Comment: Thanks! These seem like really good resources.

Comment: Ah, okay, if you want intro to LMT then I recommend [H.S. Bear](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Mathematical-Analysis-H-Bear/dp/1930665881).

Comment: Even more basic than Abbott's book is [**Yet Another Introduction to Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/052138835X) by Victor Bryant -- *Bryant's book is excellent for reading without an instructor. All the exercises have solutions. The book is full of pictures, diagrams, and other pedagogical aids. The book is excellent as a direct sequel to the standard calculus sequence and it is carefully written with this in mind.* An excellent supplementary book is [**How to Think About Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0198723539) by Lara Alcock (note that Amazon has 176 global ratings!).

Comment: [“Real Variables with Basic Metric Space Topology”](https://archive.org/details/realvariableswit0000ashr) by Robert Ash is very friendly to beginners. The volume is slim and it has a cheap [Dover reprint](https://www.amazon.com/Variables-Basic-Metric-Topology-Mathematics/dp/0486472205). There used to be a downloadable version from the late Prof. Ash‘s website, but apparently the content has been taken down.